# Detect Android Activity partially obscured without click/touch

Tags: android, kotlin

I have found that `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent` (check for `MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED` in `ev.flags`) can be used to detect if my Android app is partially obscured when it is clicked/touched by the user, but I want to be able to poll/detect if my app is partially obscured without user interaction.

Is there a way to poll this value or get an event if it changes?

Can I discern between the "obscuration" being an overlay/big window or just a floating bubble/icon at the edge of the screen?

Comment: would your app be always visible to the user? on what use case does checking an overlay become significant other than handling a click? you might want to seek alternatives because polling doesn't seem to work from my research.

Comment: I want the user to interact with both my app and one that I want to partially obscure my app. So I want to know if the other app is open.

Comment: didn't get you, so you have two apps & you want to know which app the user is currently interacting with, right?

Comment: No, I want to know "the other app" is floating above mine or not (to know if it is visible to the user or not).

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can only detect whether there's obscuring or not (that too upon a click). Maybe you can try some other methods, one thing from the top of my head is to use a boolean to store whether "your other app" is currently floating/activated; and to use that boolean from your main app.